# How to destroy gridstack before create new?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I use single page app, I create 3 Gridstack in 3 pages.
If I open page one by one, the speed for resizing widget becomes slower for each page.
But, if I reload the page it works ok.

I used Backbone's Router to open each page (not reload page).
This is my code:
Grid-satck.js

```
createGridStack: function(gridEl) {
        var options= {
            animate: true,
            width: 12,
            cell_height: 50,
            resizable: {
                handles: "e, se, s, sw, w"
            }
        };
        $(gridEl).gridstack(options);
    }
```

template: div class='grid-stack'/>

HomePageLayout.js

```
return Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "template",
    onShow: function() {
       createGridStack($(".grid-stack"));
       this.gridStack = $(gridStackEl).data('gridstack');
       this.gridStack.movable('.grid-stack-item', false);
       this.gridStack.resizable('.grid-stack-item', false);
    }
})
```

ClientLayout.js

```
return Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: template,
    onShow: function() {
       createGridStack($(".grid-stack"));
       this.gridStack = $(gridStackEl).data('gridstack');
       this.gridStack.movable('.grid-stack-item', false);
       this.gridStack.resizable('.grid-stack-item', false);
    }
})
```

LayoutSetting.js

```
return Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "template",
    onShow: function() {
       createGridStack($(".grid-stack"));
       this.gridStack = $(gridStackEl).data('gridstack');
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I use single page app, I create 3 Gridstack in 3 pages.  
 If I open page one by one, the speed for resizing widget becomes slower for each page.  
But, if I reload the page it works ok.  
This is my code:  
var options = { cell_height: 50, animation: true };  
$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);

Comment: Much better (to help get more answers) for you to edit your answer, and put it in your answer by shifting each line right 4 spaces which makes it a greyed out syntax-highlighted code block, and much easier for everyone to see and read.

Comment: You have a DOM bloating issue by the sound of it, we'd need to see much more code like how you are opening each page. Are you clearing the last page out or simply filling the DOM with more code each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
this.gridStack.removeAll();
```

or

```
destroy()
```

See docs [here](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/blob/master/doc/README.md#destroydetachgrid)